# Yii2-Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

```
    Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jts`.`employee`, CONSTRAINT `employee_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_code`) REFERENCES `client` (`client_code`))
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `employee` (`client_code`, `company_name`, `emp_email`, `emp_mobile`, `emp_first_name`, `emp_last_name`) VALUES ('12345678', 'PVPPCOE', 'saurabhkulkarni2010@hotmail.com', '+449029792183', 'Saurabh', 'Kulkarni')
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 23000
    [1] => 1452
    [2] => Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jts`.`employee`, CONSTRAINT `employee_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_code`) REFERENCES `client` (`client_code`))
)
```

I have three tables Client, Employee and create_client, out of which client and employee has two foreign keys.
This problem is showing when I try to insert data from create_client to employee which has exact same field.
What should I do so that I can insert two tables at one i.e create_client and employee

UPDATE-

Table Structure

1)client

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `client_code` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

2)create_client

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `create_client` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `client_code` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `emp_email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `emp_mobile` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `emp_first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `emp_last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

3)employee

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `client_code` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `emp_email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `emp_mobile` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `emp_first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `emp_last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is my table structure, first user will create client that means first it will update create_client. Now if user wants he can add many employee under one client code now user will update employee table from Yii2 dynamic form widget.
For using this widget I have created one table call client this will store only client_code and company name remaining data will go in employee table e.g emp_mobile,emp_email, emp_first_name, emp_last_name.

Now this problem is pop up when user first enters data into create_client table.

everything is working between client and employee table user able to enter as many employee as it wants using Yii2 dynamic form Widget but not working for create_client

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you also have a foreign key in the `employee` table referencing the `client_code` of the `client` table, so you can only use `client_code` values that already exist in the `client` table.
I don't know what the structure of the `create_client` table looks like and what its purpose is, but based on your info I assume that you should first insert the data in `client`, then in `employee` and finally in `create_client`, so that every foreign key's value exists in its respective table.

If this is not correct, please post your table structures and the data or queries that could be causing this.

Edit after your comment: I assume that your table structure looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `create_client` (
  `client_code` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `company_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_mobile` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_first_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_last_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `client_code` (`client_code`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `client` (
  `client_code` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY `client_code` (`client_code`),
  CONSTRAINT `client_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_code`) REFERENCES `create_client` (`client_code`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `client_code` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `company_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_mobile` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_first_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_last_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  KEY `client_code` (`client_code`),
  CONSTRAINT `employee_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_code`) REFERENCES `client` (`client_code`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

However, I would suggest to use `client` as the parent table and move the foreign key constraint to `create_client`, so that both `employee` and `create_client` have a foreign key of `client`. I would also like to normalise this and get rid of `company_name` in the child tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `client` (
  `client_code` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY `client_code` (`client_code`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `create_client` (
  `client_code` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `emp_mobile` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_first_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_last_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `client_code` (`client_code`),
  CONSTRAINT `create_client_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_code`) REFERENCES `client` (`client_code`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `client_code` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `emp_mobile` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_first_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_last_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  KEY `client_code` (`client_code`),
  CONSTRAINT `employee_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_code`) REFERENCES `client` (`client_code`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The next improvement would be to use the `employee` table for both unique and non-unique `client_code` inserts.  Instead of using 2 identical tables, apart from the unique key, you could do the unique validation in Yii instead of in MySQL. You can specify the table name in the `tableName()` method of the `CreateClient` model . This will remain:

```
CREATE TABLE `client` (
  `client_code` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY `client_code` (`client_code`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `client_code` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `emp_mobile` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_first_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `emp_last_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  KEY `client_code` (`client_code`),
  CONSTRAINT `employee_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_code`) REFERENCES `client` (`client_code`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This should allow you to use the dynamic form, with Client as the main model and Employee as the items model.

Comment: 1)Actually, in project i first need to create client which has client_code, comapany_name emp_mobile,emp_email,emp_FN,emp_LN this will first create and will store in create_client table in this table client_code is unique key.
2)Now, I have given a provision to admin, he can add as many employee of particular company under sane client code, so I have another table called employee in this table client_code is not a unique key.
3)in yii2 there is a widget call dynamic form by which I can create many records at one go so to implement this form i have created another table called client

Comment: this client table contain company_name and client_code

Comment: According to your initial post, you have a foreign key in `client` and in `employee`, but not in `create_client`. I edited my post and added my guess on how your table structure looks. Can you confirm this?  
You were able to insert a record into `create_client`, because that is the parent table. If you want to insert the same record into `employee`, you will need to insert a record with `client_code` '12345678' into `client` first, because that is the parent table for the foreign key of `employee`.

Comment: @Saurabh does this fix your issues or do you need any further help?

Comment: @Saurabh can you add the full output of "SHOW CREATE TABLE" on those 3 tables, so that I can also see the actual constraints? That's what is causing this issue, so it's essential. Please also add the controller code where you are saving this data.

Answer (score 1):

On Yii2 using IO Generator (Model) and MySQL I have found the following.

I have seen SET '' instead of SET NULL in update SQL statement(s) on field(s) with foreign key constraints that have caused a "Integrity constraint violation".

My "fix" is to add a default rule on the foreign key field in the model, like so:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        //
        // your other rules
        //
        [['field_name_with_foreign_key'], 'default', 'value' => null],
    ];
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

remove all foreign key checks and simplify database.
the problem lies in your foreign key structure.
learn carefully about primary keys and foreign keys.
make new database again without foreign keys then check.